# how to use np.where with .loc

Tags: dataframe, dictionary, lambda, lines-of-code

1 ,2 3 is a Month (Miesiac) and "123","222",.... is Price(cena)
cena_dict = {
1 : "123",
2 : "222",
3 : "2131231"
}

```
data = {
    "Zrodlo" : ["A","B","B"],
    "Wartosc" : [100,200,300],
    "MWh" : [10,20,10],
    "Miesiac" : [1,2,5]
}
```

## first way - work correct

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df["Test"] = np.where(df["Zrodlo"]=="A",
np.divide(df["Wartosc"],df["MWh"]),
df["Miesiac"].map(lambda x: cena_dict.get(x,"Nie znalazlem")))
```

## second way doesn't work

frame with data:

```
ceny = {
    "Zrodlo" : ["A","B","B"],
    "Cena" : [123,222,333],
    "Miesiac" : [1,2,5]
}
df_ceny = pd.DataFrame(ceny)

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df["Test"] = np.where(df["Zrodlo"]=="A",
                      np.divide(df["Wartosc"],df["MWh"]),
                      df["Miesiac"].map(lambda x: df_ceny.loc[df_ceny["Miesiac"]==x,"Cena"]))
```

print(df)

In second option I would like use .loc couse in that case I recived date in DateFrame and dictionary (way first) doesnt work

Thanks you

Comment: I would suggest you using Series instead of DF initially like this: `ceny_s = pd.Series(data = ceny['Cena'], index = ceny['Miesiac'])` and then `map(ceny_s)`